# How to Make Connection Between Different Stateful Widgets in Flutter

Tags: gridview, flutter, adapter

Hey I am adding my code here via Github

https://gist.github.com/vksBhardwaj/b4be173ef3299360311d542e55ca23b6

Comment: can u please add the code in text format?

Comment: please don't change your original question. It won't be very helpful for others.

Comment: "I uploaded because i am not able to upload code sue to some error"... And which error is that? This looks like notepad which should be easy to copy and paste.

Comment: @nick.tdr this is likely due to my ignorance, but what makes this the case?

Comment: well the question doesn't follow the guidelines and its not very clear what he is trying to ask. Should include code samples so that it easy to understand.

Comment: @vikas Upload your code in Github & add a link here.

Comment: I am uploaded my code using Github pleasehave a look . and give me a direction

Comment: Please paste your code in the body of the question instead of linking to an external resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using stateful constructor you can pass data between multiple widgets

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass values in the constructor of your adapter. In dart you can also pass function reference. Then call you function on click of of your grid item.

This will call the original function in your main class.

```
class YourAdapter extends StatelessWidget {

final Function onItemTap;

YourAdapter(
   {
    this.onItemTap
   });
    //do something like this on the onPressed of your item
    IconButton(
          icon: Icon(icon),
          color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          onPressed: () {
            //this is the method that you passed as the reference in the 
              constructor. It will call the original function.  
            onItemTap(x,y);
          },
        )
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Ok i ll implement and let you know if its working. Thanks